# How to select the last n row in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

with this code I select the first 30 row of the table:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But how to select the last 30, without changing the order?

Comment: Here you don't have any order.

Comment: Does your table have a field (or fields) that could be used to put the data in order? Perhaps a TIMESTAMP column or an auto-incrementing INT column?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like everyone is missing this part:

> But how to select the last 30, without changing the order?

First of all, clearly there is no order in the query provided. Assuming the order is ascending on some field this would be the query @DannyFox meant:

```
SELECT * FROM T
ORDER BY val
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Now imagine we have simplified data, such as `a, b, c, d, e` and that we want only 3 rows instead of 30:

```
SELECT * FROM T
ORDER BY val
LIMIT 3
```

If this returns: `a, b, c, d, e` in each row, then he would expect to get `c, d, e` in that order. The query everyone is providing:

```
SELECT * FROM T
ORDER BY val desc
LIMIT 3
```

Would return `e, d, c`. The problem with this is that it's actually changing the original order, and the OP say he didn't want to change the order. So technically, the query that would result in `c, d, e` is:

```
select * from (
  select * from t
  order by val desc
  limit 3
) s
order by val
```

Which actually changes the order twice, getting the original order back.

Comment: Looks like I beat you to it, but +1 for thinking like me. :)

Answer (score 7):

Since you are trying to avoid ordering, then the solution would be to apply it twice.

```sql
 SELECT * 
   FROM (
            SELECT * 
              FROM `table_name` 
          ORDER BY `column_name` DESC -- maybe id?
             LIMIT 0, 30
         ) `table_aliase`
ORDER BY `column_name` ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

First you need to specify an order:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY some_id ASC -- ascending order
LIMIT 30
```

If that query returns the first 30 columns, this one will return the last 30:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY some_id DESC -- descending order
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an auto incremental key/column, say `id` then here's an example

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work: `select * from table WHERE id >  ((SELECT MAX(id) from table) - 30);`

Comment: If some of the last 30 records were deleted and the id is auto-incremental you would get less than 30 results.

Comment: Yeah, that's a big maybe, especially if there are gaps between ids. `ORDER BY` clause is the pro solution, nothing less nothing more.

Comment: This answer assumes a lot about the composition of the table.

Comment: This is not the best solution. As mentioned by Shef and other `ORDER BY` is the way to go. But there was this limitation from question "... without changing the order".

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is said about an order, so you can not use ORDER BY.
There is a way to get records from a given point, but for that you need to know how many records there are, then use this counted value to provide the limits

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted FROM table

SELECT * FROM table LIMIT (counted-30),30
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my method used with PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
     $results = $row[field];
}
// Back to original order based from DB
$results = array_reverse(results);
```